# Using data with fetch - Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I can't transfer data I get from Fetch to a variable outside of fetch. First variable (currentExam) is an inside object and the seconed one (currentExam2) is an outside json. I want to do it with vanilla JS ( no jQuery)

> exams/example.json

```
 [
  {
    "question": "What time is it",
    "options": ["23:04 UTC", "03:44 UTC", "23:04 UTC", "23:04 UTC"],
    "answer": 2,
    "explain": "",
    "image": ""
  },
  {
    "question": "What time is the Sunset?",
    "options": ["22:44 UTC", "22:45 UTC", "22:46 UTC ", "06:04 UTC"],
    "answer": 4,
    "explain": "",
    "image": "example.png"
  },
  {
    "question": "What time is it afterwards",
    "options": ["23:04 UTC", "03:44 UTC", "23:04 UTC", "23:04 UTC"],
    "answer": 2,
    "explain": "",
    "image": ""
  }
]
```

> json-parsing.js

```
"use strict";

let currentExam = [
  {
    question: "What time is it",
    options: ["23:04 UTC", "03:44 UTC", "23:04 UTC", "23:04 UTC"],
    answer: 2,
    explain: "",
    image: "",
  },
  {
    question: "What time is the Sunset?",
    options: ["22:44 UTC", "22:45 UTC", "22:46 UTC ", "06:04 UTC"],
    answer: 4,
    explain: "",
    image: "example.png",
  },
];

let currentExam2 = [];
const json_url = "exams/example.json";

fetch(json_url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    const innerArr = Object.values(data);
    currentExam2.push(...innerArr);
  });

console.log(currentExam[0]);
console.log(currentExam2[0]);
```

As I run my code - I get this

```
{question: 'What time is it', options: Array(4), answer: 2, explain: '', image: ''}

undefined
```

Comment: You should use async/await then

Comment: asynchrony strikes again